# How to debug AN's red boundary box?

Tags: animation-nodes

What can I do to debug an AN network when I get the red boundary box around my Node Tree?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red border means a fatal error occured. This is probably caused by a bug in Animation Nodes, however, it may also be an error in your node tree when you disable certain error checking options. In case of a fatal error:

- A new panel called the *Problems Panel* appear. It include some suggestions and an operator to open a new issue on github to report the error as a bug. Choosing *Monitor Execution* as the *Execution Code* method in the *Developer Panel* should present more information in the problems panel like the node that causes the problem.
- The error will be printed to the terminal, so looking at the terminal should give you all the information you need, like the node that caused the problem and what exactly is the problem.

It should be noted, however, that some nodes don't have an execution function, and they contribute code to the execution unit directly, thus the terminal output will not be as useful. In this case, the terminal output should be something like:

```
  File "/home/omar/projects/blender2.80/2.80/scripts/addons/animation_nodes/execution/main_execution_unit.py", line 38, in executeUnit
    exec(self.executeCodeObject, self.executionData, self.executionData)
  File "execution: 'NodeTree'", line 3, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 11, in main
```

Which tells us that the error occurred in line 3 of the execution code of NodeTree. The *Developer Panel* have an operator that prints/write the execution code of the selected tree to the terminal/text block, the output should be something like this:

```
 ...
  9.  nodes = bpy.data.node_groups['NodeTree'].nodes
 10.  _bqracm2qds5y5ta = nodes['Expression']
 11.  __socket_False_0_bqr = None


  1.  
  2.  # Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Expression'
  3.  _result_bqr1 = _bqracm2qds5y5ta.expressionFunction()
```

Line 3 of the execution code lies in the scope of the node called `Expression`, so we know that this node is the source of the problem.

Comment: Such a detailed and informative response! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I couldn't find any error in my AN setup despite the outline being present and the nodes not working, even trying to make a simple `frame` with a `viewer` wouldn't work.

After some research I realized I had some old node tree I had totally forgot about, which was indeed the source of the error as removing it made my main tree work again and the outline disappear.